# Availability of C(2e,1s) KE protocol

Tags: key-exchange, nist, forward-secrecy

For a specific need with embedded system (key establishment with unilateral authentication and pfs) i am looking for a standard c (2e, 1s) key agreement protocol.
Unfortunatly it doesn't exist in nist sp800-56a standard (while c (1e, 2s) ka protocol is defined)

So i have a double question:
- what may be the reason for this specific miss in nist standard where all other combinations c (xe, ys)  for ka protocols (with x&y <=2) are specified ?
- does it have a sense to derive a c (2e, 1s) ka protocol from nist existing c (1e, 2s) ka protocol ?

Comment: What does ​ "c (2e, 1s) key agreement protocol" ​ mean? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Sorry for lack of acronyms definition. It refers to nist sp800-56a standard (key establishment protocols based on direct logarithm cryptography) and c (2e, 1s) for instance means key agreement protocol involving 2 ephemeral key pairs (so one for each entity) and one static (i.e long term) key pair; in that case only unilateral authentication is possible if only one entity uses a static key pair

Comment: Does the protocol need to handle the static key-pair _also_ being used for bilaterally-authenticated key agreement? ​ ​

Comment: In our case we aim to run a key agreement protocol with an embedded system not equipped with any secret element before running ka session, due to operational constraints (it is only equipped with the root certificate) and a ground system equipped with a static key pair and which must be authenticated by the embedded system. So we do not plan unless no other valid solution exists to use bilateral authentication which implies to equip the embedded system with a proper static key pair during manufacturing